# Is there a init method in iOS that is always called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, init

Is there a method that is always called in Cocoa? Many classes have `init` or `initWith`, but even worse they can be loaded from a nib or something. I don't want to have to scrape around and find how it does this in this case. I just want to set some initial variables and other things, and I want a method to subclass that I can depend on no matter if it's a `UIView`, `UIViewController` or `UITableViewCell` etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there is not such a method.  `init` comes from `NSObject` so every object can use it, and as well subclasses define their own initialization methods.  `UIView`, for example, defines `initWithFrame:` and furthermore there are init methods from protocols, such as `NSCoding` which defines `initWithCoder:`.  This is the dynamic nature of objective-C, anything can be extended at any time.  That being said, there are some patterns.  `UIViewController` almost always takes `initWithNibName:bundle:` and `UIView` almost always takes `initWithFrame:` or `initWithCoder:`.  What I do is make an internal initialize method, and just have the other inits call it.

```
- (void)initialize
{
    //Do stuff
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        [self initialize];
    }
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if(self)
    {
        [self initialize];
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that solution, so it at least removes it from the particular init method. I was hoping there was a universal init that all inits called that I could use. No such luck! Thanks. cocos2d was so much easier since all the init methods always called init eventually so you could always be sure that you'd get that. It's something you really appreciate. Otherwise you make the mistake of assigning variables or doing calls that will never happen and you try and debug... Anyways, I will stop so I don't start crying.

Comment: @borrrden sorry, isn't the **initialize** is called once for every class ?

Comment: @entropy Yes there is a method called initialize that is called once per class per run, but it is a class method (as opposed to an instance method) so this won't cause any problems.  Really you can name it anything you want, though.  I found that adding the class name on the end prevents a subclass from overwriting it accidentally .

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure that it is always called, but I am pretty sure that this is a viable option. To be perfectly honest, I can't recall that I have ever seen this method used in practice and I usually shy away from using this method (I have absolutely no idea why, probably because it's just not the cleanest and most comprehensive method to achieve this...):

```
-didMoveToSuperview()
```

From documentation:

> Tells the view that its superview changed.
>   The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can override it to perform additional actions whenever the superview changes.

Answer (score -1):

There's many ways you can write a custom initializer.

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
    if((self == [super init])) {
        self.string = string;
    }
    return self;
}
```

That's just how I write my initializers in general. For example, the one above takes a string. (you don't have to pass strings if you don't want).

Btw, init is a method. According to the header for NSObject, init has a method implementation.

Comment: -1 This doesn't seem to attempt to answer the question. @napierzaza isn't asking how to write a custom initialiser, they are looking for an initialisation method that is ultimately called by every object, regardless of class, in order to override it & provide default instance variables etc at initialisation.

Comment: I don't think this is an initializer at all.